How do eigenvalues of covariance matrix relate to discriminability form standard normal?
Given an observed data point $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we want to tell whether $X$ comes from $\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ or $\mathcal{N}(0,\mathbf{I})$, where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity. Is there some known relation between the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ and the expected 'discriminability' between these two distributions (e.g. the expected value of the log-likelihood ratio given that $X$ comes from the $\Sigma$ distribution)?
This question is motivated by the relation between generalized-eigenvalues and the Fisher-Rao distance between 0-centered Gaussian distributions (more details here).

Note that without loss of generality, we can rotate $X$ via the orthogonal eigenvector matrix of $\Sigma$ and reduce $\Sigma$ to a diagonal matrix. The standard normal is rotationally invariant so this stays the same. This will simplify any likelihood computations a great deal

@dherrera perhaps a generalized singular value decomposition is of interest here (it is also numerically robust).

@Jap88 Thanks, I didn't know about GSVD and it seems an interesting pointer for my larger problem. I don't see how it helps for this problem here though.
